# Will my site be offline if i change the DNS-Servers but A-Records stay the same?

Tags: dns

This might be a stupid question but we have to change our DNS-Servers to our own DNS-Servers because now we don't have access to our settings. So my Question is: Will my webpage be offline for a few hours if i change the Nameservers but i the A- and AAAA-Records stay the same on both Nameservers?

Comment: Your question is offtopic here as not related to programming, and in general the answer would be "no" (no interruption) except that you are leaving out so many details (like did you test the new nameservers with an undelegated test just to make sure they reply correctly? do you stop the old nameservers immediately after change? what is the TLD? etc.). If you plan to host your own nameservers but are not clear on things like that, you might want to change course and let others run DNS for you. Until you have a better understanding.

Comment: Sorry for the off topic question. 

You're right. I posted the question with too little information. But as you said it's anyway off topic.